# How to fetch geometry points (latitude and longitude) in oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, geometry, points

I want to fetch my `latitude` and `longitude` from table in `Oracle`:

*column name:* GEO_LOCATION  (type SDO_GEOMETRY)

*table name:* LOCATION_DATA

*Record:* MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,8307,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(latitude ,longitude ,0),null,null)

Comment: Did you try to search on the Internet how to extract this info?

Comment: @Bogdan Bogdanov Yes I tried but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can acccess the lat/long values with the following query:

```
select table_alias.geo_location.sdo_point.x as longitude,
       table_alias.geo_location.sdo_point.y as latitude
from yourtable table_alias
```

Comment: Here I found something useful :                                                                                         select a.id, t.x, t.y from geometry_table a, table(sdo_util.getvertices(a.geometry)) t where a.id = 1;

Comment: For a point geometry such as yours there's no need to use sdo_util.getvertices. That function is usefull when the coordinates are stored in the sdo_ordinate _array part of the geometry.

Comment: info :generally x field is equivalent to longitude field